# Why don't fundamental particles propagate outwards like classical waves?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

If particles such as electrons are vibrations in a quantum field, why doesn't their disturbance propagate like one?

I just don't quite understand why the elevated energy in that spot is pretty much self-contained.
Thinking of it as a vibration or wave innately would entail the idea of it spreading out evenly over time like ripples in a pond, wouldn't it?

Comment: Fundamental particles do spread out. What makes you think they don't?

Answer (score 17):

As stated by several people including @Ruslan, @Marco Ocram, and @John Doty in the comments, this question is related to the following classic paper by Mott:

https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1929.0205

The question Mott asked is: if a particle's wave function spreads out in a spherically symmetric way, then why are particles always observed as straight line tracks in cloud chambers? Here is an example of particle tracks in a cloud chamber, just to illustrate the point ([source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/cloud.html)):

[image]

What Mott realized is that the full quantum state is not a function of the particle's position only. The full state gives the probability amplitude for the particle to be in a certain location **and** the detector to have lit up at that location. So the full state evolves into a superposition of states, where in each state in the superposition the particle travels in a straight line in one direction and interacts with the bubble chamber in that direction, causing a straight line in the direction of motion of the electron. The full wavefunction of the electron + detector is spherically symmetric, but in each individual state in the superposition, there is only a particle track in one direction. We observe the detector in one of these states, and so always see one particle associated with a single straight line track.

Answer (score 10):

Let us consider light waves as an example:

1. The classical photon field, or the electromagnetic wave, is realized when we deal with a *huge* number of photons. The statistics that photons (bosons) obey, called [Bose-Einstein statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics) allows for such a large confluence of photons since any number of bosons can be in the same state. In this instance, they behave like classical waves.
2. Electrons, which are fermions, obey [Fermi-Dirac statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics), so the large particle limit we can have for photons will not work for electrons, since the Pauli exclusion principle applies and we can have only one fermion per quantum state.

In case you may be thinking about the other bosons in the standard model, we can also describe these bosons by classical fields in the limit of large particle numbers. For example, the gluons, the $W^\pm$ and $Z$ bosons. But whether this can be done in the real world, I'm not sure since simply put, these particles operate at very short ranges and have very short lifetimes.

Answer (score 2):

One has to keep in mind that particles obey quantum mechanics, i.e., the only predictions that can be made are probabilistic ones. There are no predictions for individual particle interactions, only the probability of a particle interacting.

[Quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) (QFT) is a mathematical tool that can be used in different physical cases to describe interactions.

> If particles such as electrons are vibrations in a quantum field, why doesn't their disturbance propagate like one?

This is a misunderstanding of the following QFT model used in particle physics to fit and predict crossections, decays, etc.:

There exists a quantum field theoretical model where interactions between particles found experimentally, [see the table,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) are modeled in the following way for calculation using [Feynman diagrams:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram)

1. Every particle in the table is a field uniform in space time represented by the plane wave function of the corresponding quantum mechanical equation that describes it, Dirac for electrons, [Klein–Gordon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) for bosons, etc.

   These are the fields, and they are like a coordinate system, unchangeable, so no motion as you envisage can occur. A simple example how coordinate systems cannot oscillate,  water waves: define a coordinate system on which the motion of the water molecules can be mapped and predicted. Do the coordinates oscillate?
2. On these fields differential creation and annihilation operators operate to create or annihilate a particle. An individual particle can at best propagate with these operators, and no collective field disturbance can happen with one particle.

Comment: What do you mean no collective field disturbance can happen with one particle? I'm pretty sure that if you have a localized electron, vacuum polarization happens around it. Also, what you said completely precludes the notion of a localized particle, as plane waves are the opposite of localized. As I understand, the plane waves are merely basis states whose contributions are added up to include the possibility of localization. Am I wrong?

Comment: In terms of fields, yes you are wrong. In terms of a model of a particle as a wave packet ,  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html yes, many frequencies are added so a localization of the particle  in terms of a solution of the Schrodinger or Dirac, or ,,, it is right, but it is not field theory. The  QFT *fields* are like a coordinate space on which the creation and annihilation  differential operators operate to model the motion of a particle.  Only with a creation operator a particle appears, with a given probability.

Comment: How do you mean the motion of a particle? No real particle is a plane wave, and plane waves only have momentum, they don't "move" in that they are equally everywhere at once. As I understand, all you can do is calculate things like interaction strength between plane waves of different particles. Also, when calculating Feynman Diagrams, you often integrate over momentum space, summing contributions to a diagram matrix element from all the different possible plane waves. How is that different from the wave packet being a sum of plane waves?

Comment: this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @LiamClink  the shape of the contribution is different than a wave packet? it must depend on the total wavefunction too, which can have any mathematical form given by the mathematics. You are confusing mathematics with the physical observations that have to be fitted with the mathematical solutions, and be predictive. First come the observations, and then the modeling. In  particle field theory the plane waves are just a coordinate system, unchangeable. It  is the creation and annihilation operators operating on the fields that model interactions.

Comment: @gemmima  in my opinion 1. answers that there can be no wave disturbance on fields that are immovable, a coordinate system.

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei  I have upvoted Andrews answer. I think he clears the fact that Hawking radiation cannot be detected with astrophysics observations which deal with large mass bodies, and ansers  the question at the end and the title. Maybe what is , not wrong, but too much to expect readers to read all the references that puzzle you with their partial questions.

Answer (score 1):

One should distinguish the wave function from the particles it describes. The particles are point, or close to point particles. The wave functions propagate outward and with them the probability of finding particle charge, energy-momentum, etc.